# Github organization permissions

Tags: github, organization

I have a main repo that students are forking to do their homework. From the student's view of the repo, the list of collaborating teams is small (their individual team and my teacher team). However, from my view (as admin), there is a long list of teams with access. As a result, students are able to see within other students' private repos.

What is the correct way to manage this so that teams can fork a main repo, and limit access to that repo among teams.

Comment: can you provide more information on where those private repos are located. Is it an intranet network with a shared directory for the central repo and private repos on each student's machine. Or you have an internet based repo with ssh access?

Comment: All running on github.com.

Comment: I thought github has only two options: your repo is open for everyone or you pay for a private repo that nobody can see. Correct me anyone if I am wrong.

Comment: The repo is part of a github organization (https://github.com/blog/674-introducing-organizations), so that if a user in the organization forks a private repo, it remains private.

Comment: I see. Looks like a question to the github support.